# Does the expected return of a stock ETF depend on the current interest level? At which interest rate are stock ETFs no longer recommended?

Tags: stocks, etf, interest-rate, interest

Is there an interest rate such that there is no point in putting money into the stock market (e.g. in a stock ETF that models the stock market) but where the interest rates of almost risk-free investments result in higher returns than the expected returns of such an ETF that models the stock market? In this context I was wondering whether the expected return of such an ETFs is correlated (positively or negatively) with the **current** interest rate. The question is not whether changes of the interest rate will affect the stock market / ETFs but rather: Is the expected return of a stock ETF during the following year the same regardless of the interest rate at the beginning of that year?

Note: As pointed out in the comments the question was poorly phrased. I edited it, basically what I meant with “ETF” in the original version was an ETF that models the stock market.

Comment: What type of ETF? A bond ETF or a stock ETF?

Comment: ETF is an efficient way to diversify within a specific sector or across the market. Your question doesn't really make sense the way it's phrased.

Comment: Over what time period, as part of what strategy? Bonds are often thought of as mostly a low-risk way to preserve value, with other parts of the portfolio being expected to gain value but at higher risk.

Comment: Yes for bonds ETFs

Comment: If it was this easy, giant hedge funds would sell all their stocks, lowering stock prices, increasing the percentage of the stock price that the dividend was (as it does not change) i.e. increasing the effective interest rates on stocks (and therefore stock ETFs). As a rule of thumb, every effect you could possibly think of is already accounted for in the stock price.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the question was poorly phrased. When I wrote ETF I meant the stock market or an ETF that tries to model the stock market. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @user253751 dividends are not fixed - companies can lower dividends, and often do if the stock price falls for fundamental reasons. And dividends on stocks are not equivalent to interest on bonds (they lower the price of stocks accordingly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Efficient Market Hypothesis, the risk- and time-adjusted "expected value" of any investment with a sufficiently competitive market is zero. If the an asset is selling for a price lower than value that people "expect" it to have in the future, then those people who think it's undervalued will buy it, bidding up the price until it reaches the expected value. Also, your use of the term "ETF" is a bit odd. An ETF is simply a way of aggregating assets. For all of your questions, the answers relate to the attributes of assets, and how those assets are aggregated is irrelevant. The answers will be the same for an ETF, mutual fund, advisor-managed portfolio, etc., if the underlyings are the same.

> Is there an interest rate such that there is no point in putting money into ETFs but where the interest rates of almost risk-free investments result in higher returns than the expected returns of ETFs?

The market pays a premium for risk, so risk-free investments have the lowest returns. Taking on risk means that your expected return is higher.

> In this context I was wondering whether the expected return of ETFs is correlated (positively or negatively) with the current interest rate.

According to the EMH, return is risk premium plus time value, and higher interest rate means higher time value, so yes, interest rates are positively correlated with gross nominal investment return. Basically, the risk-free interest rate is the time value, and the return of any investment with risk is the time value/interest rate plus the risk premium.

However, the effects are complicated, as interest rates are correlated with a bunch of other things, some of which are positively correlated with returns, and other negatively.

Also, you do say "The question is not whether changes of the interest rate will affect the stock market", so that suggests that you understand that there a difference between the steady-state effect of a consistent interest rate, versus the transitory effect of a *change* in interest rate.

Comment: Thanks, that’s helpful! And good point regarding my use of the term ETF, you are right that what I actually meant was rather about the behaviour of assets in general and not about the aggregation.

Answer (score 4):

One way to measure expected return of any investment is the risk-free rate of interest plus some "premium" in exchange for any additional risk. This goes for bonds, stocks, real estate, and any ETF that contains any combination of them. The amount of that premium is proportional to the amount of risk in the investment (a mathematical representation of that proportion is "beta"). If the expected rate of return were *lower* than the risk-free rate, then investors would ignore it and flock to risk-free investments. That would drive the price of those investments down (due to low demand) and hence increase their *expected* return. Or, put another way, investors would not be willing to pay a price higher than what would give them an appropriate level of return for the extra risk.

So no, there is no risk-free rate of interest at which there is "no point" to invest in ETFs. Risky investments will *always* have a higher expected return than risk-free investments.

> I was wondering whether the expected return of ETFs is correlated (positively or negatively) with the current interest rate.

Positively - as risk-free interest rates go up, the expected returns of risky investments go up (all else being equal).

> Is the expected return of an ETF during the following year the same regardless of the interest rate at the beginning of that year?

No - the expected return can change based on risk free rates, market expectations, and many other factors depending on the investment.

But, it's important to understand what "expected" means. It does NOT mean "guaranteed" or even "likely". It's essentially the average of a distribution of possible returns, so an investment can earn more or less than the expected return, but *on average* the market expects it to return a certain amount.

Comment: Thanks! Is it also conceivable that higher interest rates cause a lower volatility of the stock market and therefore ETFs might have the same or a lower expected return but a higher volatility / risk? And if this is possible in theory (in the sense that it is no contradiction), is it known whether this is the case in practice? That is, does the interest rate have an effect on the variance of the stock market? Is that one aspect of what you meant with “all else being equal”?

Comment: By "all else being equal" I meant things like credit spreads (for bonds) In theory, risk-free rates could go up but if credit spreads went down (less risk of default) then corporate bond rates could go down. But that seems like an unlikely scenario. So there _could_ be a similar effect with volatility - if vol goes down more than rates go up, the net expected return could go down (the risk premium would be less)

Answer (score 0):

Even if we get hyperinflation, a better rate of return loses value more slowly, so inflation really doesn't directly affect the choice directly.

The question is simply where your money is expected to get a good rate of return relative to the risk involved. Acceptable risk depends partly in when you will need the money (which is why young folks saving for retirement can accept higher risk than folks close to retirement, if the rewards are improved enough to compensate), and partly on your own comfort level.

The stock market as a whole has historically averaged about 8% return. An appropriately diversified mix -- so you are tracking the market as a whole -- can come pretty close to that with minimal active management. (After the recent correction and recovery, my mix of mutual funds is currently at about 7.5% and continuing to drift back up though if I'd needed large amounts of it while it was near the bottom that could have been ugly; time horizons again). If I knew if an investment that gave better return at what I considered acceptable risk, if course I'd move at least some of my money into that.

If you can find a better investment, within your risk tolerance, by all means take advantage of it. For many, perhaps most, of us who have the money for long term savings, a good index funds strategy is as good a choice as any other and better than most, and requires almost no effort once your strategic mix has been defined. That's not easy to improve upon.

Answer (score -2):

All securities, including shares and bonds, are valued based on the money they bring in to the person who owns them. Anyone would be ambivalent between getting $100 from a share next year, and getting $100 from a bond next year, apart from the much higher uncertainty of the payout from the share.

Interest rate is a measure of how much people would prefer to have money now instead of later. If the interest rate is 5% that means people - on average - are ambivalent between getting $100 now or $105 next year. This is used to calculate a value of a security *now* based on what it will pay out in the future. If I know the bond or share will pay out $105 next year and the interest rate is 5%, it's worth $100.

If I know the bond or share will pay out $105 next year and the interest rate is 20%, it's worth $87.50. So, yes, all else being equal, prices of all securities should be expected to go down when interest rates go up. And so does the expected return. It's still $105 but now that $105 is 20% higher than what you paid, not 5% higher.

All else is not equal, of course, and in a very complicated way that nobody can predict. Since nobody can predict it, we'll just have to pretend it is equal, and hope it's equal on average. (Maybe when the interest rate goes up, the share won't pay out $105 any more.)

This comes about because the army of analysts at the giant banks are doing the work for you. When they calculate the price of an ETF, and their formula says it should be $87.50, and they look at the market and it's $90, they sell a bunch and that makes the price go down. If it says $85, they buy a bunch and that makes the price go up. They make money doing this, but not a huge amount, because they're all competing with each other for pennies.

Comment: @keshlam seems to be repeating what Accumulation's answer says